Set AzureML Job outputs path to working directory
I am training a computer vision model in AzureML and try setting the outputs directory to match the location of my logs/artifacts, i.e. my execution work dir 'exe/wd'. I code/prototype locally and upload jobs via mlclient. Training script, environment, computes etc. works.
Writing files with:
with open(filepath, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(obj)

stores writes files to the wrong location.
I would like to store/see/access my checkpoints here for convinience:
Outputs+Logs
Job definition:
from azure.ai.ml import Output



job = command(
    inputs={
        'data':Input(
                type="uri_folder",
                path=f"{data_asset.id}",
                mode=InputOutputModes.RO_MOUNT
        )},
    outputs={
        'outputs':Output(
            type='uri_folder',
            path = './outputs',
            mode  =InputOutputModes.RW_MOUNT
        )}
    ,
    code="<path>",
    command=az_cfg.COMMAND_TRAIN,
    environment=f"{az_cfg.ENV_NAME}{az_cfg.ENV_VERSION}",
    display_name=az_cfg.DISPLAY_NAME,
    compute = ci_name,
    evironment_variables={ 
      "DATASET_MOUNT_BLOCK_BASED_CACHE_ENABLED": True
      },
    experiment_name=az_cfg.EXPERIMENT_NAME
      
)



What I expected to happen was to see my outputs folder in the "Outputs+Logs" tab in the studio.
After some research I found that outputs generated during execution will be stored in the default workspaceblobstorage. How can I change the outputs to be in the workspace working directory?
When saving a model with mlflow the log and save will land in the right place. However, I cannot use mlflow here.
I am not sure if this is expected behaviour and just not possible or am I missing something out?
Any help is highly appreciated.

According to this documentation, the local path like ./home/username/data/my_data is supported only in Inputs and not for Outputs.
So, as you said, you need to log models and details in the default workspaceblobstorage or your custom blob store and download them to your current workspace directory.
Below is the command job code.
job = command(
    code="./src",  # local path where the code is stored
    command="python main.py --diabetes-csv ${{inputs.diabetes}}  --model_out ${{outputs.output}}",
    inputs={
        "diabetes": Input(
            type="uri_file",
            path="https://azuremlexamples.blob.core.windows.net/datasets/diabetes.csv",
        )
    },
    outputs={
        'output': Output(
            type=AssetTypes.CUSTOM_MODEL,
            path = 'azureml://subscriptions/<subscriptions_id>/resourcegroups/<resourcegroup>/workspaces/jgsml/datastores/workspaceblobstore/paths/ML_output/',
            mode  = InputOutputModes.RW_MOUNT
        )}
    ,
    environment="AzureML-sklearn-1.0-ubuntu20.04-py38-cpu@latest",
    display_name="sklearn-diabetes-example",
)

Code snippet to save the model in main.py:
import joblib
from pathlib import Path
model = train_model(params, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)
joblib.dump(model, (Path(args.model_out) / "model_1.pkl"))

After the job is completed successfully, download it to the current directory using the code below.
returned_job = ml_client.create_or_update(job)
ml_client.jobs.download(returned_job.name, download_path="./job_output", all=True)

Output:


Thanks for the solution above, quick question, when I run this, the code in the "./src" folder gets uploaded to my default blob storage account as a new container. This is cluttering up my storage account. Is there a way to control where this code gets uploaded in my default storage?

See a full question for the above comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78643575/control-where-source-code-for-azure-ml-command-gets-uploaded

It seems Microsoft encourages to use MLflow and who needs to store the artifacts manually if not using MLflow. But some trick from this doc for v1 and it works on v2 as well.
The only thing to do is to prepend the ./outputs or ./logs to the output path. You don't need the output args, which provides an Azure blob path, then the outputs or logs folder will be saved to Outputs + logs. Please note that your artifacts will be nested in the folder.
If you'd like to make the output path parameterized, you can add an input arg and pass it to command.
